# Rails update to 5.2 error: The direct method can't be used inside a routes scope block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando subir a versão do Rails da versão 5.1.2 para a versão 5.2.2 e estou tendo o seguinte erro quando tento subir o servidor da aplicação: `The direct method can't be used inside a routes scope block (RuntimeError)`

Segue o log completo do erro:

```
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        92: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        91: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        90: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/Documents/GitHub/umanni_hr/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        89: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
        88: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
        87: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`<top (required)>'
        86: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`load'
        85: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        84: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        83: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        82: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        81: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        80: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/Documents/GitHub/umanni_hr/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        79: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        78: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        77: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        76: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        75: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        74: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        73: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        72: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        71: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        70: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        69: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        68: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        67: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        66: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        65: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        64: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        63: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
        62: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
        61: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
        60: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
        59: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
        58: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
        57: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        56: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        55: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        54: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        53: from config.ru:in `<main>'
        52: from config.ru:in `new'
        51: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        50: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        49: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        48: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        47: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        46: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        45: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        44: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/skylight-core-3.1.2/lib/skylight/core/probes.rb:119:in `require'
        43: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        42: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        41: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        40: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        39: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        38: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/Documents/GitHub/umanni_hr/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        37: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
        36: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        35: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        34: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        33: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        32: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        31: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        30: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        29: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        28: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        27: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        26: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        25: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        24: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        23: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:130:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        22: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
        21: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
        20: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:30:in `block in updater'
        19: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:20:in `reload!'
        18: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `load_paths'
        17: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `each'
        16: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in load_paths'
        15: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
        14: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        13: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
        12: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/zeus-0.15.14/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:74:in `load'
        11: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/zeus-0.15.14/lib/zeus/load_tracking.rb:82:in `load'
        10: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
         9: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
         8: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/config/routes.rb:3:in `<main>'
         7: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:414:in `draw'
         6: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:430:in `eval_block'
         5: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:640:in `with_default_scope'
         4: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:879:in `scope'
         3: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:641:in `block in with_default_scope'
         2: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:641:in `instance_exec'
         1: from /Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/config/routes.rb:6:in `block in <main>'
/Users/almirsantosfilho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:2099:in `direct': The direct method can't be used inside a routes scope block (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almir Santos isso pode ser algum problema de configuração da sua aplicação antiga, para rodar a sua aplicação e descobrir onde está o problema você pode seguir esses passos abaixo:

Obs: garanta que você está usando algum sistema de controle de versão para poder comparar as mudanças e manter tudo o que é requerido para sua aplicação rodar.

1. Rodar a rake::task de atualização com o comando:

   - rails app:update e autorize que a task sobrescreva tudo o que pedir.
2. Verifique as mudanças e altere somente o que é requerido.

   - se estiver usando git, pode executar o comando git diff .
3. Tente rodar a aplicação com o mínimo de mudanças possíveis para localizar exatamente onde está o problema de configuração.

Acho que com isso consegue resolver seu problema.
Me avise caso tem problema durante esse processo.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem uma chamada `direct` no seu arquivo `config/routes.rb` que não é permitido, por estar dentro de um `namespace` ou `scope`.

Está na [documentação](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/CustomUrls.html):

> NOTE: The direct method can't be used inside of a scope block such as
>   namespace or scope and will raise an error if it detects that it is.

Para resolver isso, você pode criar um controller para rotear isso, ou tirar do `scope` ou do `namespace`.